# No plist file available in Xcode C++ App

Tags: c++, xcode, versioning, macos-sierra

I'm new to Xcode. I am using version 8.3.3 on MacOS 10.12.5 (Sierra) to develop an experimental command line application. I want to set up a version number for the application. According to instructions in Apple documentation and many other places I should be able to do this under the General tab for the project. However, under the General tab Xcode does not seem to be able to find a plist file and instead 
[displays a 'Choose info.plist File' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUCpT.png).

When I click the click the button Xcode displays a [selection dialog containing a project icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8mB0.png), but no sign of an info.plist file and no obvious way to navigate to or create one.

I have tried the technique described at Youtube (v=gYh4_80jHDk: sorry -- can't post it as a link as I'm also new to Stack Overflow!) but to no avail. It just gives me another 'Choose info.plist File' button.

I expect I'm missing something obvious, but it's not obvious to me. I'd be grateful for any help!
Many thanks